# xamarin form + odata

Tags: xamarin.forms, simple.odata

Can any one tell me how to retrive data from OData service using Simple.Odata.Client with in xamarin forms ?

I try by following way :

In Portable Project

```
public App()
{
  GetDocument();
}

public async void GetDocument()
{
     String result = await ODataServiceAgent.GetDocuments(skipCount);
}
```

In OData Service Calls

```
public static async Task<string> GetDocuments(int skipCount)
        {
            string json = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                var client1 = new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings(ServiceConstant.sURL_Base, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ServiceConstant.NCUserName, ServiceConstant.NCPassword))
                {
                    IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true,
                    //OnTrace = (x, y) => Console.WriteLine(string.Format(x, y)),
                });


                string commands = string.Format(ServiceConstant.sURL_WholeDataByPagging, ServiceConstant.servicePaggingTopCount, skipCount);

                IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> configs = client1.FindEntriesAsync(commands).Result;

                List<IDictionary<string, object>> configList = ((List<IDictionary<string, object>>)configs.ToList());

                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configList);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string excepstionMessage = ex.Message;
            } 
            return json;
        }
```

while actual call is happen using "FindEntriesAsync" line its not responding

Comment: you need to await FindEntriesAsync()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It in the call to Result. In general it's not a good idea to call Result or Wait on async methods: it *may* work in some environments (like desktop Windows) but it will deadlock in others, especially mobile ones. So just await it, don't do .Result or .Wait.